# check for null or undefined values in a an object of type array or type object

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

am testing the following scenarios

1. if every value in an object is null or undefined it should
   return true
2. if every value in an array is null or undefined values it should
   return true

my test is failing with an object who has nested array or object or an array who has nested array or objects

```
  describe('hasNullOrUndefined', () => {
    test.each`
      mockData                                                           | expected
      ${[{ a: null, b: null, c: null }, { a: null, b: null, c: null }]}  | ${true}
      ${{ a: null, a: null }}                                            | ${true}
      ${{ a: null, a: "a1"}}                                             | ${false}
      ${{ a: null, a: false }}                                 |         | ${false}
      ${[{ a: 'a1', b: 'b1', c: 'c1' }, { a: 'a2', b: 'b2', c: 'c2' }]}  | ${false}
      ${{ a: 'a1', b: 'b1', c: { a: 'a2', b: 'b2', c: 'c2' } }}          | ${false}
      ${{ a: null, b: null, c:[null,null] }}                             | ${true}
      ${{ a: null, b: null, c: {a: null, b: null} } }}                   | ${true}

      ${{}}                                                              | ${true}
      ${[null, null]}                                                    | ${true}
      ${[false, false]}                                                  | ${false}
      ${[true, true]}                                                    | ${false}
      ${[]}                                                              | ${true}
      ${[2259.93, 4259.99]}                                              | ${false}
      ${[, undefined]}                                                   | ${true}
    `(
      'should return the correct value $expected with mockData is $mockData',
      ({ mockData, expected }: TestCase<boolean>) => {
        const result = service.hasNullOrUndefined(mockData);
        expect(result).toEqual(expected);
      }
    );
  });
```

In my service

```
  public hasNullOrUndefined= (data: object | unknown[]): boolean => {
  
      if (this.isObject(data)) {
        return this.isObjectEmpty(data);
      } else {
        return Array.isArray(data) ? this.isArrayEmpty(data as []) : false;
      }
    
  };

  private isObject = (object: Object): boolean => {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(object) === '[object Object]';
  };

  private isObjectEmpty = (object: Object): boolean => {
    return Object.keys(object).every(key => {
      return Array.isArray(object[key])
        ? this.isArrayEmpty(object[key])
        : Object.values(object).every(value => {
          if (value === null || value === undefined ) {
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        });
    });
  };

  private isArrayEmpty = (element: []): boolean => {
    return Object.keys(element).every(key => {
      return this.isObject(element[key])
        ? this.isObjectEmpty(element[key])
        : element[key] === null || element[key] === undefined ;
    });
  };
```

Thank you for your kind responses

Comment: The expected results don't fit the description. An array is not `null` or `undefined`. According to the description the input `[[null]]` should output false.

Comment: `[null, null, c: [a: null, b: null] ]` is not even valid. This object has a duplicate key `{ a: null, a: "a1"}`

Comment: btw, what happens to an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

You could check

- if `value` is an array, then check every value ,
- if `value` is truthy and an object, then check all values or
- check if `value` is `null` or `undefined`.

```js
const
    isNullOrUndefined = value => {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) return value.every(isNullOrUndefined);
        if (!value && typeof value === 'object') return Object
            .values(value)
            .every(isNullOrUndefined);
        return value === null || value === undefined;
    }
```

Comment: Just to state the obvious, if one needs to call this method, for an array, it should be like so: `const isArrayNullOrUndefined = someArray.every(isNullOrUndefined);`. And, in case one needs to use it on an object (checking that all values are null or undefined), then: `const isObjectValuesNullOrUndefined = Object.values(someObject).every(isNullOrUndefined);`. I'm in awe of how succintly this method achieves its objective.

Comment: @jsN00b, why not try it?

Comment: @NinaScholz i have tried the following it failed     `public  isNullOrUndefined = (value:object | unknown[]):boolean => {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) return value.every((value)=>value === null || value === undefined);
        if (!value && typeof value === 'object') return Object
            .values(this.isNullOrUndefined(value))
            .every((value)=>value === null || value === undefined);
        return value === null || value === undefined;
    }`